# Telling Python to stop comparing in a for loop when it gets to the last character

Tags: python, python-2.7

At the moment I have code that is looking through a huge string. It compares the string like this:

```
a = 0
for letter in my_str:
    a += 1
    if letter <= my_str[a]:
```

It keeps comparing all the way until the end when I get a 'string index out of range' error. I know it is because it is trying to compare the last character in the string to the next character (which doesn't exist) How to fix this! I feel like I have tried everything. Help appreciated.

EDIT: Seems as though I have just figured out my solution... thanks anyways.

Comment: You can post your own solution and accept it if you think it is the best.

Comment: Incidentally, you should never name your variable "str": this can lead to a conflict with the string datatype, and, potentially, weird behavior.

Comment: @abought I changed it to `my_str`.

Comment: @user1294377 `str` is the name of the python class for strings so don't use it for your variables as you are shadowing the built-in.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I just added another if statement at the beginning like the following..

```
if a < len(str):
```

Don't know why it took me so long to figure that out!

Answer (score 2):

Using pairwise recipe from [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes)

```
>>> from itertools import tee, izip
>>> def pairwise(iterable):
        "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
        a, b = tee(iterable)
        next(b, None)
        return izip(a, b)

>>> text = 'abc'
>>> for x, y in pairwise(text):
        if x <= y:
            pass
```

Comment: That might be a little scary for a beginner, but `zip(text, text)` and `zip(text, text[1:])` aren't so bad to play with, to get a feel for index-free iteration.

Comment: @DSM I like to use itertools whenever I can, plugging in a recipe can't hurt even if you don't understand it as long as you know that it works, it comes from a trusted source so the user can conclude that it must be efficient. Also he did say *At the moment I have code that is looking through a huge string* so the shorter `zip` version would be inefficient.

Comment: you could be right, although I don't always seem to be impressed by what people consider "huge"..

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using indexes to work with strings when iterating over them. Instead of comparing the current letter to the next one, compare the current letter to the *previous* one, which you have saved from the last pass through the loop. Initialize the "previous" variable outside the loop to something sensible for the first pass.

```
lastletter = ""
for letter in text:
    if lastletter <= letter:   # always true for first char
        # do something
    lastletter = letter
```

Answer (score 1):

what you probably want is

```
for i in range(len(str)-1):
    if str[i] <= str[i+1]:
```